# Why is my Python code running so slow? How can I speed it up?

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, for-loop

I am working on a code related to stock management. I wrote a code about the latest date to supply new products for the products that will be out of stock.

This is my current data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SKU' : ["20651","27394","28443","27766","23767","24704","27824","19612","27339","27851"],
    'DailyMean': [6,9,6,7,9,3,4,8,7,1],
    'Stock': [8,15,9,5,4,11,19,16,28,29],
    'LeadTime': [5,6,6,8,3,7,4,1,8,1],
    'alert': [False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,False,True],
    'LeadDate': ["2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11","2021-05-11",]                    
})
```

```
    SKU   DailyMean  Stock  LeadTime    alert   LeadDate
0   20651      6       8       5        False   2021-05-11
1   27394      9      15       6        False   2021-05-11
2   28443      6       9       6        False   2021-05-11
3   27766      7       5       8        False   2021-05-11
4   23767      9       4       3        False   2021-05-11
5   24704      3      11       7        False   2021-05-11
6   27824      4      19       4        True    2021-05-11
7   19612      8      16       1        True    2021-05-11
8   27339      7      28       8        False   2021-05-11
9   27851      1      29       1        True    2021-05-11
```

This is the code I wrote.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    new_stock = df.Stock[i]
    x = 0
    
    while((new_stock - (df.LeadTime[i] * df.DailyMean[i])) > 0):
        new_stock = new_stock - (df.LeadTime[i] * df.DailyOrder[i])
        if new_stock >= 0:
            x = x + 1

    df.LeadDate[i] = df.LeadDate[i] + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
```

This is what I expected.

```
    SKU   DailyMean  Stock  LeadTime    alert   LeadDate
0   20651      6       8       5        False   2021-05-11
1   27394      9      15       6        False   2021-05-11
2   28443      6       9       6        False   2021-05-11
3   27766      7       5       8        False   2021-05-11
4   23767      9       4       3        False   2021-05-11
5   24704      3      11       7        False   2021-05-11
6   27824      4      19       4        True    2021-05-12
7   19612      8      16       1        True    2021-05-12
8   27339      7      28       8        False   2021-05-11
9   27851      1      29       1        True    2021-06-08
```

This code also runs for a very long time on big data. How do I optimize this code to run faster.

Comment: make sure that data is not stored inside the code file but it is stored outside the code file ins ome sort of format such as json, csv, etc...

Comment: Actually I get my data from SQL database

Comment: Is DailyMean a computed column? Because I don't see it included in the code for your example?

Comment: What is the size of database? (In MegaBytes) because getting it on SQL might be slow for some really large database

Comment: And Correct me if I am wrong, Are you able to retrieve database as a whole or you have to make multiple queries

Comment: You can also make some caching mechanism that queries database and then store it whenever the program is called. It can be refreshed every 1 hour by the program.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is bad algorithmic complexity: Your code in the loop has O(n) complexity where you want O(1).

I don't quite understand the semantics of your code, so I guess that you want to achieve the following:

- You have a quantitiy of a resource (called `stock`)
- There will be a periodic reduction of that resource (which you expressed by subtracting `leadTime * dailyMean`)
- You want to know: For how many periods will I still have the resource available -- or, put differently: When will I run out of this resource?

So, the question your code is answering: If I have 500 units in stock, and I periodically sell 10, in how many periods will I run out of stock?

You implemented this using a loop:

```py
stock = 500
daily_reduction = 10
days = 0
while (stock - daily_reduction) >= 0:
    days += 1
    stock -= daily_reduction
```

The important aspect here is the following: For this computation, the loop will have to run `days` times, so we have O(n) complexity. It is easy to see how we could compute this much faster:

```py
stock = 500
daily_reduction = 10
days = stock // daily_reduction  # // is integer divion, which we want here.
```

This code only has to do one division to get the result, so it runs in O(1) complexity.

Also, you have a `pandas.DataFrame`, yet you're doing your computations manually in python. You probably want to do something like:

```py
# element-wise division of the elements: How often can we subtract until we hit 0?
subtract_counts = df.Stock // (df.LeadTime * df.DailyMean)

# transform numbers to datetimes
days_to_add = subtract_counts.apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(days=x))

# element-wise add
df.LeadDate += days_to_add
```

Note: This computation is a little bit different: Your while loop had condition `> 0`, but here we're semantically using `>= 0`, but I think you wanted to do that anyway? Please correct me if I misunderstood.

This approach should run appropriately fast, also for larger amounts of data. Benchmarks on the (very small) sample data you gave indicated a 4x speed up, even though the inner while loop is not executed once for most columns.

Comment: I'll add here: What most confuses me is that you subtract by `(leadTime * dailyMean)`. I think, for this to have proper real-world meaning, what you rather want to do is divide by `dailyMean` to find out when you will run out of stock, and then subtract `leadTime` from these timepoints to find out when you have to order so the order arrives before you run out of stock.